# I want to send an email to all the users who has access to my SharePoint site collection including subsite and its users it's for SP 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, send-email

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I want to send an email to all the users who has access to my site collection including subsites and users who has access to subsites.

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: The purpose of the forum is only to point you in the correct direction, rather than completing the work for you. Google is your friend, here's a good place to start: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/get-started-managing-sharepoint-2010-with-powershell-cmdlets/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Callum Crowley ! I am expecting a direction or suggestions for my requirement.. i have done a lot of research for the same but I could not figure out to send mails to all the users from my site in a single go. Any leads will be much appreciated 